# Camera calibration after recording video - will it work?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, pixel, camera-calibration

I am interested in getting the distance between two pixels from an object in a video (real-world distance). I did not calibrate the camera before recording the video. If i calibrate the camera now, will it work? Or do i have to re-record the video after doing the calibration?

I am new to image processing and camera calibration and would appreciate any help!

Comment: No problem if the camera remains unchanged (:Either the camera does not have some kind of functional mechanism that changes its internal parameters, or such a function exists but is not used.)

Comment: e.g. if the camera has auto-focus feature, and it was working during the video capturing... camera parameter will be changed according to the focus changing, so it may ba able to be problem.

Comment: By the way, estimating real-world-distance requires some information to do it. So, the point "is the your video has such information?" may be more important than camera calibration.

Comment: @fana Thanks alot! Do you know how i can get the distance between 2 pixels in real-time, from a video using opencv? I am tracking a specific object in a video and i want to know the distance between the two pixels in the object with time. I checked previous posts, but i couldn't find anything for finding the pixel distance in real-time from video.